# Facebook not allowing Admin to get publish_actions permissions on development app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am facing a weird problem. I am asking for publish_actions permission for my app, and trying to test it with my own id which has the admin role in the app, but when I try to get permissions for the app, Facebook asks me to submit the app for review.

I effectively can't develop the app due to this, and it's very frustrating.

Facebook is supposed to let the admin get the publish_actions permission for the app.

How can I fix this?

[image]

The user in question is the Administrator for this app. I am totally stuck here! Feel like giving up on FB development and doing something else.

Comment: Facebook doesn't ask you to submit it. They are warning you so you don't start asking people that don't have a role on the app

Comment: No that's not correct. It says "This does not let the app post to Facebook"

So no, I can't post to facebook.

Comment: Sure you should never ask for publish_actions when the user logs in

Answer (score 1):

After much much pain, I finally figured this out. Like @WizKid mentioned in his [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943065/facebook-not-allowing-admin-to-get-publish-actions-permissions-on-development-ap/33864086#comment40616309_25943065) (the second one I believe is actually mistaken), that's simply a warning. What's not clear is that the user needs to click Okay (granting login permission) and after that there's **another** follow up dialog that prompts for the `publish_actions` permission.